# I only want to access one specific calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, calendar

On my mobile app, we access the native calendar on iOS. There are multiple calendars on the devices, but I only want to access one specific calendar from my employer. How can I do this "filtering"?

We use cordova/ionic to access the native calendar.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use [listCalendars()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/calendar/#listCalendars) to list all available calendars and then find the one you want:

```
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

myCalendar:any;

constructor(private platform: Platform, private calendar: Calendar) { 
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        calendar.listCalendars().then(
          (calendars) => { 
            calendars.forEach((calendar) => {
                if(calendar.name === "my employer"){
                    myCalendar = calendar;
                }
            });
          },
          (err) => { console.log(err); }
        );
    });
}
```